# Connect to MAMP local server (MacBook) from Windows computer

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I'm having trouble connecting to a local server hosted on a MacBook/MAMP. My .NET application (running on a Windows computer) smoothly connects to another Windows machine (MySQL server) with the same connection string "server=[computer's name]; user id=xxxx; password=xxxx; database=xxxx" but when I use this MacBook's name, I get the following error:

"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Note: File Sharing is turned on

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like either your MacBook does not offer such service to the network (service not running, only listening locally or blocked by a local firewall), or you have a general network routing issue between those two systems.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Firewall was off the whole time :(

Comment: Then try a connection by a raw `telnet <ip address> <port humber>` and see what happens. A timeout or something about MySQL?

Comment: take a look to the bind parameter in your my.cnf. it is possible that the server only listen on 127.0.0.1. if so change it to 0.0.0.0 to listen also on the external adapter (ip). if you change it you must restart the database

Comment: Where can I find this my.cnf file?

Comment: So I created one because MAMP doesn't come with one, added the bind address parameter. No luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might experience the same issue, the problem was that my MacBook wasn't visible to Windows machines. Go to System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing > Options and check your Account and Share files and folders using SMB.